# How to get all html data between 2 div with rails Nokogiri gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I want to try get all html data between 2 div using Nokogiri gem:

Ex:

```
<div class='job-details__divider'></div>
<h2 class='job-details__second-title'>...</h2>
<div class='job-details__top-reason-to-join-us'>
...
</div>
<h2 class='job-details__second-title'>...</h2>
<div class='job-details__paragraph'>
...
</div>
<h2 class='job-details__second-title'>...</h2>
<div class='job-details__paragraph'>
...
</div>
<h2 class='job-details__second-title'>...</h2>
<div class='job-details__paragraph'>
...
</div>
<div class='jd-page__employer-overview'></div>
```

The result data is html code between 2 class (job-details__divider and jd-page__employer-overview)
Any one can give me a solution? Thank!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using Nokogiri's XPATH 1.0 support by applying the [Kayessian method](https://marc.info/?l=xsl-list&m=122572106903286&w=2) of node-set intersection:

```
$nodeset1[count(. | $nodeset2) = count($nodeset2)]
```

In your case, `$nodeset1` is all siblings preceding `div[@class='jd-page__employer-overview']` and `$nodeset2` is all siblings following `div[@class='job-details__divider']`.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

# nodeset1: All nodes after div.jd-page__employer-overview
nodeset1 = "//div[@class='jd-page__employer-overview']/preceding::node()"

# nodeset2: All nodes following div.job-details__divider
nodeset2 = "//div[@class='job-details__divider']/following::node()"

intersection = doc.xpath("#{nodeset1}[count( . | #{nodeset2}) = count(#{nodeset2})]")

puts intersection.to_html
```